# How gradually plot a curve in console

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, console

So the following code creates a gif file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k')

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line.axes.axis([0, 10, 0, 1])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line],
                              interval=25, blit=True)
ani.save('test.gif')
plt.show()
```

When I run it, it shows the final result of the animation in the console.
However, I would like to see the entire animation in the console.
How can this be done?

It should also work when there is a large number of frames.

EDIT:
I am using Python 3.8.5 and Spyder 4.2.1. I would like to use the 'plots' pane of Spyder.

Comment: Your code/animation worked in my console (using python-3.8.5-anaconda), although the zoom was strange :) It also worked with ipython and Spyder. What Python version are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by showing the animation in the console? Do you mean like the Spyder console, or a Jupyter notebook? In a Python terminal, plots open in a external window. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I clarified the question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is an interesting question. I looked up for solutions, but I couldn't find any unfortunately. Maybe the behavior is hard-coded into Spyder. I found a explicit reference in the documentation about the Plots pane showing static images: `The Plots pane shows the static figures and images...`. Source: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/plots.html . Maybe an expert in Spyder can help.  I look forward to the answers :)

Comment: Thanks, so I have to use the IPython console then

Comment: Or another pop up window

Comment: Yeah, that's probably good for now... until we get a super-expert answer ;). In Spyder or iPython, you can also use commands like `%matplotlib qt` to display external windows with gifs.

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont have enough reputation for a comment

But as far as i know ani.save() is blocking try to switch the last two lines.

```
    plt.show(block=False)
    ani.save("test.gif")
```

The window will close as soon ani.save() is done if you don't want that change block to True but it will not save until you closed the window

Comment: Thanks @Jack! I tried to switch the last two lines, but unfortunately it still doesn't show in the Plots pane.

Comment: @Riemann do you have ffmpeg or pillow installed?

Comment: I have Pillow 9.1.0